# Return 0 during aggregate sum in mssql for columns that have null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to find the sum of prices in my product table of different categories in group by statement, but I wish to return 0 if any of the price values is null or 0:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Categories (Name) VALUES ('Fruits') ,('Electronics'),('Clothes'),('Furnitures');

INSERT INTO Products (Name,Price,CategoryId) VALUES
('Oranges',2,1),
('Mangoes',NULL,1),
('Bananas',10,1),
('Dell',700,2),
('Samsung',200,2),
('Hp',800,2),
('Apples',20,1),
('Ginger',NULL,1),
('Sweater',220,3),
('Jeans',110,3),
('Door frames',200,4),
('Window Frames',100,4),
('Bed',1000,4),
('Chair',NULL,4)
```

The Result after selecting all Products that are fruits with their respective categories is:

```
SELECT
    Products.id,
    Products.name,
    Products.price,
    Categories.name
FROM
    Products
INNER JOIN Categories ON
    (Categories.id = Products.categoryid)
WHERE Products.categoryid=1
```

[image: List of Fruit Products]

As it can clearly be seen two of the fruits have null values in price. When I run

```
SELECT Categories.name , SUM( Products.price) FROM  Products INNER JOIN Categories ON (Categories.id = Products.categoryid)
GROUP BY Categories.name
```

[image: Sum of Prices by Category]

But unfortunately the query returns sum of products with null price values:
**I wish to return 0** for all categories that have products with null prices

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer here. Include categories with/wtithout null/0 etc.

Comment: I wonder why you get so many answers on such a unprecise and unclear question. Would be great if you provide both sample input and expected results even if some answers already show what you looked for. This will help people with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of SUM() function with CASE Statement

```
SELECT category, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Price IS NOT NULL AND Price <> 0 THEN Price ELSE 0 END) as TotalPrice
FROM Products
GROUP BY category;
```